# Creating subtables in MongoDB using Kettle

Tags: mongodb, etl, kettle

I have two PostgreSQL tables with the following data:

**houses**:

```
-# select * from houses;
 id |    address
----+----------------
  1 | 123 Main Ave.
  2 | 456 Elm St.
  3 | 789 County Rd.
(3 rows)
```

and **people**:

```
-# select * from people;
 id | name  | house_id
----+-------+----------
  1 | Fred  |        1
  2 | Jane  |        1
  3 | Bob   |        1
  4 | Mary  |        2
  5 | John  |        2
  6 | Susan |        2
  7 | Bill  |        3
  8 | Nancy |        3
  9 | Adam  |        3
(9 rows)
```

In Spoon I have two *table inputs* the first named **House Input** with the SQL:

```
SELECT
  id
, address
FROM houses
ORDER BY id;
```

The second *table input* is named **People Input** with the SQL:

```
SELECT
  "name"
, house_id
FROM people
ORDER BY house_id;
```

I have both *table input's* going into a *Merge Join* that uses **House Input** as the first step with a key of `id` and **People Input** as the second step with a key of `house_id`.

I then have this going into a *MongoDb Output* with the database **demo**, collection **houses**, and Mongo document fields `address` and `name`. (As I am expecting MongoDB to assign the `_id`).

When I run the transformation and type `db.houses.find();` from a Mongo shell, I get:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52083706b251cc4be9813153"), "address" : "123 Main Ave.", "name" : "Fred" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52083706b251cc4be9813154"), "address" : "123 Main Ave.", "name" : "Jane" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52083706b251cc4be9813155"), "address" : "123 Main Ave.", "name" : "Bob" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52083706b251cc4be9813156"), "address" : "456 Elm St.", "name" : "Mary" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52083706b251cc4be9813157"), "address" : "456 Elm St.", "name" : "John" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52083706b251cc4be9813158"), "address" : "456 Elm St.", "name" : "Susan" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52083706b251cc4be9813159"), "address" : "789 County Rd.", "name" : "Bill" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52083706b251cc4be981315a"), "address" : "789 County Rd.", "name" : "Nancy" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52083706b251cc4be981315b"), "address" : "789 County Rd.", "name" : "Adam" }
```

What I **want** to get is something like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52083706b251cc4be9813153"), "address" : "123 Main Ave.", "people" : [
        { "_id" : ObjectId("52083706b251cc4be9813154"), "name" : "Fred"} ,
        { "_id" : ObjectId("52083706b251cc4be9813155"), "name" : "Jane" } ,
        { "_id" : ObjectId("52083706b251cc4be9813155"), "name" : "Bob" }
    ]  
},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52083706b251cc4be9813156"), "address" : "345 Elm St.", "people" : [
        { "_id" : ObjectId("52083706b251cc4be9813157"), "name" : "Mary"} ,
        { "_id" : ObjectId("52083706b251cc4be9813158"), "name" : "John" } ,
        { "_id" : ObjectId("52083706b251cc4be9813159"), "name" : "Susan" }
    ]  
},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52083706b251cc4be981315a"), "address" : "789 County Rd.", "people" : [
        { "_id" : ObjectId("52083706b251cc4be981315b"), "name" : "Mary"} ,
        { "_id" : ObjectId("52083706b251cc4be981315c"), "name" : "John" } ,
        { "_id" : ObjectId("52083706b251cc4be981315d"), "name" : "Susan" }
     ]
 }
```

}

I know **why** I am getting what I am getting, but can't seem to find anything online or in the examples to get me where I want to be.

I was hoping someone could nudge me in the right direction, point to an example that is closer to what I am trying to accomplish, or tell me that this is out of scope for what Kettle is supposed to do (Hopefully not the latter).

Comment: As an aside, I don't think you should be using a Merge Join step in your transform. Instead, join the tables in the database and use the output of the join in Kettle. Your database will be able to do the join better than Kettle: the Kettle join steps are best for data coming from streams populated by either datasources without a native join or data from mixed sources.

Comment: Excellent point @GGordonWorleyIII.  This is just simple data that I am using to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish in MongoDB.  But yes, if the data sources are in the same DB, a join in the SQL of the Table Output would be the best way to go.  BTW I am getting close to a resolution, hopefully I will be able to post something soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out creating subtables is all in the *MongoDB Output* step.

First make sure that you have the **Upsert** and **Modifier update** checked on the *Configure connection* tab.

Then on the *Mongo Documents field* tab enter the following (The first line is column names):

```
Name    | Mongo document Path | Use field name | Match field for upsert | Modifier operation | Modifier policy
--------+---------------------+----------------+------------------------|--------------------+---------------- 
address |                     | Y              | N                      | N/A                | Insert
address |                     | Y              | Y                      | N/A                | Insert
name    | people[0]           | Y              | N                      | $set               | Insert
name    | people[1]           | Y              | N                      | $push              | Update
```

Now when I run `db.houses.find();` I get:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520ccb8978d96b204daa029d"), "address" : "123 Main Ave.", "people" : [ { "name" : "Fred" }, { "name" : "Jane" }, { "name" : "Bob" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520ccb8978d96b204daa029e"), "address" : "456 Elm St.", "people" : [ { "name" : "Mary" }, { "name" : "John" }, { "name" : "Susan" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520ccb8a78d96b204daa029f"), "address" : "789 County Rd.", "people" : [ { "name" : "Bill" }, { "name" : "Nancy" }, { "name" : "Adam" } ] }
```

Two things I would like to note:

1. This assumes that my address are unique and that my name's are unique within a house.  If this is not the case I would need to make my id's from my OLTP tables to id (not _id) fields in MongoDB and *Match for field upsert* on my house id.
2. As @G Gordon Worley III pointed out above, if these two tables are in the same database, I could do the join in the *Table Output* step, and this would be a two step transformation (and faster).